# jquery combobox do not accept functional output

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

I use a jquery combobox to create a combobox.

If I type like this, it works perfectly:
 `<select id="combobox"><option>1</option></select>`

However, if I type like this:

`<select id="combobox"><td id=xx></td></select>`
and a function() change  innerHTML of id=xx to `<option>some value</option>`

but this do not work out.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Could you please provide a code sample?

Comment: Yep, I forgot to quote my code...

Comment: In general, jQuery UI widgets only know about the elements that are there when they're initialized. Dynamic changes to the elements are not automatically picked up by the widget, you need to reinitialize it so they'll see them.

Comment: Could you tell me how to reinitialize the changes so when call the jquery, it is there? actually I call the function by onload, but it do not work out.